# CREATE USER MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, createuser

Error with dropping tables:

```
SQL query:

DROP user IF EXISTS  's01'@'%';


MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to 
use near 'if exists 's01'@'%'' at line 1
```

Error without dropping tables:

```
SQL query:

/*Students*/ CREATE User 's01'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY  'pw1';


MySQL said: Documentation

#1396 - Operation CREATE USER failed for 's01'@'%'
```

Example of some of my code:

```
Drop user if exists 's01'@'%';

flush privileges;

/*Students*/
Create User 's01'@'%' Identified by 'pw1';
```

I don't exactly know what is wrong. I looked it up and it said add flush privileges, but I still get the same two errors.

Comment: maybe a problem with privileges? - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-user.html

Comment: `flush privileges` -> not needed with proper user manipulation SQL statements.

Answer (score 1):

Check your version of mysql with `select version();`.  The `IF EXISTS` option for `DROP USER` was added in 5.7.  If you're not using 5.7, then that likely explains your first error.

Check if the user exists by querying `mysql.user` table.

> select user, host from mysql.user where user = 's01';

Also since you are not specifying a hostname, just execute

> DROP user IF EXISTS  's01';
>   Create User 's01' Identified by 'pw1';

The wildcard host (@'%') is implied.

Also execute `SHOW GRANTS` to verify that your user has the correct privileges to create and drop users.